# Match every element in database document's array in Mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Is there a way to Match every element in database document's array in Mongo?

For instance, with document:

```
{
    Stuff: ['chicken', 'stock']
}
```

Is there a query that would take as input in some way ['chicken', 'flavored', 'stock'] and return this document, but wouldn't return it with an input of just ['chicken']?

Comment: Can you clarify behavior you need ? Why [a, b, c] should return [a, b] and not [a] ? You should write rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by combining multiple operators to perform a double-negation that's a bit hard to keep track of in your head (at least it is for me!):

```js
// Find the docs where Stuff only contains 'chicken' or 'stock' elements
db.test.find({Stuff: {$not: {$elemMatch: {$nin: ['chicken', 'stock']}}}})
```

So the `$elemMatch` with the `$nin` is finding the docs where a single element of the `Stuff` array is not in the set of strings, and then the parent `$not` inverts the match to return all the docs where that didn't match any elements.

Starting with docs of:

```js
db.test.insert([
    {Stuff: ['chicken']},
    {Stuff: ['chicken', 'stock']},
    {Stuff: ['chicken', 'flavored', 'stock']}
])
```

The above query returns:

```js
{
  "_id": ObjectId("53dec1c5393fa0461f92334c"),
  "Stuff": [
    "chicken"
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("53dec1c5393fa0461f92334d"),
  "Stuff": [
    "chicken",
    "stock"
  ]
}
```

Note, however, that this will also return docs where `Stuff` is either missing or has no elements.  To exclude those you need to `$and` in a qualifier that ensures `Stuff` has at least one element:

```js
db.test.find({$and: [
    {Stuff: {$not: {$elemMatch: {$nin: ['chicken', 'stock']}}}},
    {'Stuff.0': {$exists: true}}
]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a text index should help here, as it is a OR match, sortable by score, so that the result with the best match can easily be found. The more of the search words are found, the better the score. Plus, the text search provides stemming and stop words. In the example given that would mean that "chickens" and "the chicken" would give identical results.

```
 db.yourCollection.ensureIndex({"Stuff":"text"})
 db.yourCollection.find({ $text: { $search:"chicken stock", $language:"en" } },{ score: { $meta: "textScore" } })).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } ).limit(whatEverYouDeemAppropriateInt)
```

Please see [the MongoDB docs about Text Indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#text-indexes) for further details.